# Splitting a column in excel into two columns keeping the leading zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Trying to find a faster way to change this format from one column (`A`) split into 2 columns (`B` and `C`) as in  the example below:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 978-BD71151-001-0 | 978-BD71151-001 | 0 |
| 978-BD71151-002-1 | 978-BD71151-002 | 1 |
| 978-BD71151-002-2 | 978-BD71151-002 | 2 |
| 978-BD71151-002-3 | 978-BD71151-002 | 3 |

I used `text to columns` which splits each string on the `-` delimiter. But unfortunately it also removes the leading zeros from the numbers in the second last column, `D` in the example below.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 978-BD71151-001-0 | 978 | BD71151 | 1 | 0 |
| 978-BD71151-002-0 | 978 | BD71151 | 2 | 0 |
| 978-BD71151-002-1 | 978 | BD71151 | 2 | 1 |
| 978-BD71151-002-2 | 978 | BD71151 | 2 | 2 |

This means I have to first prepend `00` to each row of column `D` before using a formula to join columns `B` through `D` back together.

Just trying to figure out how to separate the last digits while keeping the other  values intact.

Comment: When you do the text to columns, one of the steps allows you to choose the output of the value.  You can tell it to use `Text` instead and it will leave the leading `0`s

Comment: You can also format the columns where the data will end up as Text before you use the text-to-columns feature.

Comment: Try to set to the TEXT formatting.

Answer (score 0):

#### SUBSTITUTE & TEXTSPLIT Functions

---

###### STEP 1

Build the initial formula using `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the 3rd dash with an arbitrary unique placeholder character that we will later use to split the string in step 2.

[Microsoft Excel's SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)
`=SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text, [instance_num])`

| Element | Value | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | A1 | ## *Address of your string "978-BD71151-001-0"* |
| old_text: | "-" | ## *dash character* |
| new_text: | "" | ## *arbitrary unique placeholder character* |
| instance_num: | 3 | ## *3<sup>rd</sup> instance of the dash character* |

**Initial Formula**: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","",3)`

---

###### STEP 2

Complete the final formula by wrapping the initial formula from step 1 in a `TEXTSPLIT` function using the placeholder character as the column split delimiter.

[Microsoft Excel's TEXTSPLIT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7)
`=TEXTSPLIT(text,col_delimiter,[row_delimiter],[ignore_empty], [match_mode], [pad_with])`

| Element | Value | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","",3) | ## *from `SUBSTITUTE` above"978-BD71151-0010"* |
| col_delimiter: | "" | ## *our placeholder character* |

**Final Formula:** `=TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","",3),"")`

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 978-BD71151-001-0 | =TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","",3),"") |  |
| **2** | 978-BD71151-002-1 | =TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","",3),"") |  |
| **3** | 978-BD71151-002-2 | =TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","",3),"") |  |
| **4** | 978-BD71151-002-3 | =TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"-","",3),"") |  |

---

###### STEP 3 (Optional LAMBDA)

Single formula that will populate all the rows. Has the benefit of a single place for changes.

<sup>***Note:** My inclusion of `ARRAYTOTEXT` in the formula limits the usability of each instance to about 1,600 rows (1,639 in testing). More than that will give you a `#CALC!` error.  For more than 1,600 rows, use `VSTACK` to combine multiple instaces.*</sup>

```
=LAMBDA(x, TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(x,"-","",3)),"",","))(A1:A1600)
```

Combining formulas using VSTACK

```
  =VSTACK(
     LAMBDA(x, TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(x,"-","",3)),"",","))(A1:A1600),
     LAMBDA(x, TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(x,"-","",3)),"",","))(A1601:A3200)
   )
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 978-BD71151-001-0 | =LAMBDA(x, TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(x,"-","",3)),"",","))(A1:A1600) |  |
| **2** | 978-BD71151-002-1 |  |  |
| **3** | 978-BD71151-002-2 |  |  |
| **4** | 978-BD71151-002-3 |  |  |

---

##### Sample Output

This output is the same regardless if you use the formula from step 2 or step 3.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 978-BD71151-001-0 | 978-BD71151-001 | 0 |
| **2** | 978-BD71151-002-1 | 978-BD71151-002 | 1 |
| **3** | 978-BD71151-002-2 | 978-BD71151-002 | 2 |
| **4** | 978-BD71151-002-3 | 978-BD71151-002 | 3 |

Comment: Since I think OP wants to put the text together again, they can simply use a variation of your answer `=SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-"," ",3)`. i.e. substitute the 3rd dash with a space.

Answer (score 0):

The output which you're trying to achieve can be done by `Text to Columns` feature available in excel, with few small (yet important) modifications. Here I will try to show you the process in a chronological order.

First, I have copy-pasted the data that you provided:

[image: The sample data]

Then you select the data in `Column B` and format it as text:

[image: Formatted as text]

Now go to `Data` -> `Text to Columns`, click the `Delimited` Radio button and proceed by clicking `Next`.

Put a `Check mark` in `Others` and enter `-` in the adjacent box:

[image: second step in the process]

Click `Next` and Proceed.

In the next screen, select the third column Under data preview, select a destination cell, or leave it as it is if you want to replace in the original cell, and click the `Text` radio button:

[image: The final step]

Click finish and confirm if any confirmation screen pops up. There you go, you'll get the number prepended with the preceding zeroes:

[image: Final Product]

I hope this helps :)
Do let me know if you're still confused.